How to disable screen capture shortcut in Microsoft Edge
On a mac, is there a way to disable the new screen capture shortcut (cmd + shift + S) in Microsoft Edge?  That conflicts with the same shortcut in Google Translate

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464293/how-do-i-add-change-or-remove-a-key-command-shortcut-from-a-menu-item

That doesn't seem to apply to removing a shortcut for the Edge browser

Ah, shame. If it doesn't follow the Apple Toolbox guidelines you'll need to see if it has an internal solution.
